# Loop Through Folders & Subfolders for files with Wildcard Search

Tags: excel, vba, loops, wildcard

Good Morning,

I have some code that is doing the basis of what I want, BUT I just need to take it one step further for it to work perfectly. Currently I'm pulling every file in the folders and subfolders which is proper, but now I need to select only files that have a particular version label: "v5.3.xlsx" so I can open them, make adjustments and close. I've tried every version of a wild card search I can think of but I'm not terribly well versed in VBA so I was hoping someone could kick this over the finish line for me. Any help is very much appreciated!

```
    Sub loopAllSubFolderSelectStartDirectory()

'Another Macro must call LoopAllSubFolders Macro to start to procedure
Call LoopAllSubFolders("C:\Users\smith\Desktop\Excel Test File\Client\")

End Sub

'List all files in sub folders
Sub LoopAllSubFolders(ByVal folderPath As String)

Dim fileName As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim fullFilePath As String
Dim numFolders As Long
Dim folders() As String
Dim i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath & "\"
fileName = Dir(folderPath & ".", vbDirectory)

While Len(fileName) <> 0

    If Left(fileName, 1) <> "." Then
 
        fullFilePath = folderPath & fileName
 
        If (GetAttr(fullFilePath) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
            ReDim Preserve folders(0 To numFolders) As String
            folders(numFolders) = fullFilePath
            numFolders = numFolders + 1
        Else
            'Insert the actions to be performed on each file
            'This example will print the full file path to the immediate window
            Debug.Print fullFilePath
        End If
 
    End If
 
    fileName = Dir()

Wend

For i = 0 To numFolders - 1

    LoopAllSubFolders folders(i)
 
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `fileName = Dir(folderPath & "*v5.3.xlsx")`?

Comment: That's exactly what I thought, but the code just doesn't seem to work after making that change. None of the files are pulled to the immediate window, so none of the changes I would need to implement would go through.